Draft.js: Is there a way to preserve a custom style?
I'd like to ask whether there is a way to save custom style classes e.g. css class that only provides color when getting the current content of draft.js EditorState.This is my draft.js editor component with some features disabled due to lack of screen space.
As of now I am doing the colors within the editor via CustomStyleFn, however no matter where I look I cannot see the answer how to store it, so that when I reload the custom styles are preserved (I am not seeing strikethrough as a custom style as it actually is present in the source code). Any clues?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
